# Android data binding TextView value of String with fall back to @StringRes

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

context: data binding with a ViewModel, which gets data from a remote source in the form of JSON. I want to display a textual value from that JSON in a TextView, but if the data is absent in the JSON, I want to fall back to a string defined in strings.xml.

`android:text="@{viewModel.theText}"`

How I currently solved it is with a custom binding adapter that accepts an `Any`, and checks if the value is an Int or String:
`app:anyText="@{viewModel.theText}"`. The viewModel has something like `val theText = json.nullableString ?: R.string.placeholder`.

I'm guessing that this is a problem more people deal with, and I was hoping if someone knows a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide Application context to your ViewModel or Resources and then do something like this:

```
val theText = json.nullableString ?: resources.getString(R.string.placeholder)
```

The other option would be keep using binding adapter like you do but I would wrap text input in another object like this:

```
data class TextWrapper(
   val text: String?,
   @StringRes val default: Int
)

@BindingAdapter("anyText")
   fun TextView.setAnyText(textWrapper: TextWrapper) {
   text = textWrapper.text ?: context.getString(textWrapper.default)
}

val theText = TextWrapper(text = json.nullableString, default = R.string.placeholder)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an adapter to handle this use *Null coalescing operator operator* `??` in xml.

Try below code:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.theText?? @string/your_default_text}"
```

Use case :

The null coalescing operator (??) chooses the left operand if it isn't `null` or the right if the former is `null`.

P.S: lean more about DB and expressions here-> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of this operator, but the fallback stringRes also needs to come from the viewmodel. Therefore I've accepted the other answer